# What do the SSM PingStatus values mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm

I am looking at SSM instance ping status (PingStatus) information, as returned by the describe_instance_information [boto3 calls](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.describe_instance_information) or as displayed in the SSM console for Managed Instances.  But it is not clear to me what the values represent in all cases.  From documentation such as [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-remote-commands.html#rc-healthapi-win) I understand there are 3 status values:

- Online
- ConnectionLost
- Inactive

"Online" seems pretty self explanatory, and I can make a relatively safe guess at what "ConnectionLost" means, but then what does "Inactive" mean?  **What exactly do each of these ping status values indicate?**  I want to understand what is different about "ConnectionLost" and "Inactive" so I can respond more appropriately to the status when I see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read at the bottom of the same documentation.

If the status is

**Online**

> Then your instance is ready to be managed using Run Command.

**Inactive**

The instance has one or more of the following problems.

> - SSM Agent is not installed.
> - The instance does not have outbound internet connectivity.
> - The instance was not launched with an IAM role that enables it to communicate with the SSM API, or the permissions for the IAM role are
>     not correct for Run Command. For more information, see Create an IAM
>     Instance Profile for Systems Manager.

The above document does not contain more information about connection lost, but here is something relevant.

**connection lost**

If an **instance fails a health check**, AWS OpsWorks Stacks autoheals registered Amazon EC2 instances and changes the status of registered on-premises instances to connection lost.

You can check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196701/terminal-hang-when-lost-connection-and-ssh-is-on/196724) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/registered-instances-manage.html) for connection lost.

Comment: I didn't see the first two definitions, probably because the documentation lists them only under the Linux section and not the Windows section for some reason.  ConnectionLost is still a guess I suppose, but given that the SSM agent does health checks this seems like a reasonable conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Its shows connection lost when you don't have correct IAM role assigned to the instance or when SSM agent version is not updated